# Behavior of the resolvent near the boundary of the spectrum

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

My question is, in some sense, a continuation of the question below.

[Isolated singularities of the resolvent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671818/isolated-singularities-of-the-resolvent)

Suppose $T\in B(H)$ has no eigenvalues, pick $x\in H$, $x\neq 0$, and consider the analytic function $R(\cdot, x):\rho(T)\to H$ defined as $R(\lambda, x)=(\lambda I-T)^{-1}x$ (the evaluation of the resolvent operator at $x$). Is it true that for any $x\neq 0$, we can find $\mu\in\partial(\sigma(T))$ (boundary of the spectrum) such that $R(\cdot, x)$ is unbounded "near" $\mu$?

The answer is positive, I think, when the spectrum of $T$ is finite (or even when it is a convergent sequence). This follows from the answer to the question linked above and it actually holds even without the condition on the point spectrum.

Also I can easily construct a counterexample when $T$ has eigenvalues. Take a bounded operator with the spectrum the unit disk and $0\in\sigma_p(T)$. Then for $x\in\ker(T)$, $R(\lambda, x)=\lambda^{-1}x$ and this is bounded near any point on the boundary of the unit disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H^{2}(D)$ be the Hardy space of holomorphic functions on the unit disk $D$. That is, $f \in H^{2}(D)$ iff $f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_{n}z^{n}$ has a power series expansion in $D$ with $\|f\|^{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|f_{n}|^{2} < \infty$. The shift operator $S$ defined by $(Sf)(z)=zf(z)$ is an isometry, i.e., $\|Sf\|=\|f\|$; and the spectrum $\sigma(S)$ is the closed unit disk $\overline{D}$. $S$ has no point spectrum.

Let $L^{2}(T)$ be the Lebesgue measurable, square-integrable functions on the unit circle $T$, and define $(Uf)(z)=\frac{1}{2}zf(z)$ for all $z \in T$. Then $\sigma(U)=\frac{1}{2}T$ consists of the circle of radius $1/2$ centered at the origin in the complex plane.

Let $H=H^{2}(D)\times L^{2}(T)$ and let $V(f,g)=(Sf,Ug)$. The spectrum of $V$ is $\overline{D}$, and $V$ has no eigenvalue. Furthermore, $(V-\lambda I)^{-1}(0,(U-\lambda I)^{-1}f)$ is uniformly bounded for $|\lambda| > 1$, regardless of $f \in L^{2}(T)$, which supplies a counter-example to your conjecture.

Comment: Concerning the finite spectrum case ... If $\sigma(T)$ is finite, and if $T$ has no eigenvectors, then, for each $x$,  $(\lambda I -T)^{-1}x$ has either an essential singularity or a removable singularity at $\mu \in \sigma(T)$ because a pole of order $k > 0$ implies $(\mu I-T)^{k}x=0$ but $(\mu I-T)^{k-1}x\ne 0$, which gives an eigenvector $y=(\mu I-T)^{k-1}x$ with eigenvalue $\mu$. If $(\lambda I - T)^{-1}x$ has an entire extension, then, because $(\lambda I - T)^{-1}x$ vanishes at $\infty$, you'll end up with $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}x =0$ everywhere, which forces $x=0$. You're right about this.

Comment: Isn't the above true regardless of whether $T$ has eigenvalues? $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}x$ cannot have an entire extension, therefore some isolated singularity $\mu$ is either essential or pole. Either case gives that $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}x$ is unbounded near $\mu$. This should work in the case when spectrum is a convergent sequence (the limit becomes isolated if all other singularities can be removed), or, even more generally, when we can remove all isolated singularities in finite number of steps. Hope this makes sense. Thank you for your counterexample.

Comment: My essential singularity remark was tangential to the issue. The real issue, as you point out, is that $(\mu I-T)^{-1}x$ cannot have an entire extension unless $x=0$. So, if the spectrum is isolated, there are interesting implications of this fact. Another side issue which is related: if $\oint_{C}(\mu I-T)^{-1}\,d\mu=0$ for some simple, closed, rectifiable curve in $\rho(T)$, then the interior of $C$ must be in the resolvent $\rho(T)$.